# Error while sending file to WCF: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I am trying to upload file using wcf service. I am getting `The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request` at:

```
ds = WcfSpend.RegisterSupplier("blah", new SpendWcfRef.FileData 
{ 
    FileName = myFile.FileName.ToString(), 
    BufferData = file, 
    FilePosition = 1
});
```

WCF:

```
public DataSet RegisterSupplier(string SupplierId, FileData file)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    return ds;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISPEND
{

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet executeProcedure(string procedurename, string[] paramsName, string[] paramsValue, int num);

    [OperationContract]
    DataSet RegisterSupplier(string SupplierId, FileData file);

    //[OperationContract]
    //bool UploadFileData(FileData fileData);
}

[DataContract]
public class FileData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] BufferData { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int FilePosition { get; set; }
}
```

APPLICATION:

```
ds = WcfSpend.RegisterSupplier("blah", new SpendWcfRef.FileData
{ 
    FileName = myFile.FileName.ToString(), 
    BufferData = file, FilePosition = 1
});
```

Apllication config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISPEND" 
                closeTimeout="00:01:00"     
                openTimeout="00:01:00" 
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                allowCookies="false" 
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
                messageEncoding="Text" 
                textEncoding="utf-8" 
                transferMode="Buffered" 
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                        proxyCredentialType="None" 
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

WCF WEB CONFIG:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="myBindingForBigArrays"
                openTimeout="00:10:00" 
                closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                sendTimeout="00:10:00" 
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="64"
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Please add an actual question and some more detail to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Aaron I am getting `The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request` where i invoke wcf method in my application. I am trying to send  a file to wcf.

Comment: It could be related to size, though you appear to be returning an empty `DataSet`.  You've defined bindings for the client and the service with larger values, but they're not being used because they're not assigned to an endpoint via the `bindingConfiguration` attribute on the `endpoint` element, unless you're doing it in code you didn't show.

Comment: @Tim I do not know much about web configuration. Please help me out if you can. What do I do?

Comment: Are you hosting the service in IIS?  How do you create the client - did you use Add Service Reference, or are you doing it via something like `ChannelFactory<T>`?  The answers to those questions have some infuence on the answer I'll give.

Comment: @Tim as of now i am just running the code on my visual studio.. I added service using  Add Service Reference

Comment: `BufferData = file` - Can you shed more light on this. Whats the variable `file` being set to

Comment: @AshutoshVyas file is binary array of the file i am trying to upload

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few things that are resulting in the error you are seeing.  The first thing I would recommend is that you assign the binding configurations you created to an explicitly defined endpoint.   Something like this:

```
<!-- This goes in the <system.serviceModel> section -->
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="myBindingForBigArrays"
              contract="<namespace>.ISpend" />
  </service>
</services>
```

The above is the configuration for the service.   Make sure you fully qualify the contract name with the namespace, and the service name needs to be the same as the name in the markup of the .svc file.

You would do something similar for the client, except it would be the `<client>` tag, rather than `<service>`.

If you don't specify the binding configuration to use in the endpoint, then WCF will use the default (lower) values for the binding type you selected.   An alternative is to make the binding configuration the default for that kind of binding, by omitting the `name` attribute.

If this doesn't solve the issue, you can also try adjusting the `maxRequestLength` value for the `<httpRuntime>` element in `<system.web>`.  `<system.web>` is a child of `<configuration>`:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: my application config looks liek this now ` <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <client name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="s"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="myBindingForBigArrays"
                  contract="SpendWcfRef.ISpend"  />

      </client>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>`

It says the element service has invalid child element

Comment: @Arbaaz - `<services>` is a child of `<system.serviceModel>`, just like `<client>`.  In other words, you don't put the `<client>` section under the `<services>` section.

Comment: I feel so dumb. What do I put in  address="" ?  This is my service path : `http://localhost:60537/SPEND_WCF/Service.svc`